# сохранение положения элементов после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, javascript

Надо сохранить на сервер элементы, которые были активированы, и при каждой последующей загрузке, восстанавливать прежнее их положение.

Механика такая - выпадающий список, при клике на какой-либо из подпунктов, создаётся соответствующий ему элемент, а он сам удаляется из списка, и наоборот, при удалении элемента, в выпадающий список добавляется его название. Планировал передавать через пост 1 и 0 при добавлении удалении элемента, чтобы потом как-то воссоздать прежнюю картину исходя из этого, но не додумал как.

Рассматривал вариант с сохранением на сервер создаваемого кода, чтобы потом его передавать при загрузке страницы, но это пахнет костылём, я в деле не так давно, но хотел бы сделать качественно.

Вот, собственно, сам код.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.tab_add', function() {
  var post = {};
  post.ajaxRequest = true;
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'country') {
    $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="country"><a id="primeCountry" href="#baseWin2" aria-controls="baseWin2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchCountry">База стран</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="country"></button></li>');
    post.country = 1;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'currenci') {
    $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="currenci"><a id="primeCurrencies" href="#baseWin3" aria-controls="baseWin3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name ="searchCurrenci">База валют</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="currenci"></button></li>');
    post.currenci = 1;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'package') {
    $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="package"><a href="#baseWin4" aria-controls="baseWin4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchPackage">База пакетов</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="package"></button></li>');
    post.package = 1;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'activitidirection') {
    $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="activitidirection"><a href="#baseWin5" aria-controls="baseWin5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchActivitiDirection">Направление деят-ти</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="activitidirection"></button></li>');
    post.activitidirection = 1;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'branch') {
    $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="branch"><a href="#baseWin6" aria-controls="baseWin6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchMonitoringBranch">Отрасль</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="branch"></button></li>');
    post.branch = 1;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'industrialdirection') {
    $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="industrialdirection"><a href="#baseWin7" aria-controls="baseWin7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchIndustrialDirection">Промышленное направление</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="industrialdirection"></button></li>');
    post.industrialdirection = 1;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'measuri') {
    $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="measuri"><a href="#baseWin8" aria-controls="baseWin8" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchMeasuri">Ед. Измерения</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="measuri"></button></li>');
    post.measuri = 1;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'fo') {
    $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="fo"><a href="#baseWin9" aria-controls="baseWin9" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchFo">Федеральный округ</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="fo"></button></li>');
    post.fo = 1;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'region') {
    $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="region"><a href="#baseWin10" aria-controls="baseWin10" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchRegion">Регион</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="region"></button></li>');
    post.region = 1;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'logistic') {
    $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="logistic"><a href="#baseWin11" aria-controls="baseWin11" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchLogistic">Логистика</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="logistic"></button></li>');
    post.logistic = 1;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'quality') {
    $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="quality"><a href="#baseWin12" aria-controls="baseWin12" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchQualityMeasure">Качество</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="quality"></button></li>');
    post.quality = 1;
  }
  $(this).remove();
  console.log(post);
});

$(document).on('click', '.delite_tabs', function() {
  var post = {};
  post.ajaxRequest = true;
  $(this).parents('li').remove();
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'country') {
    $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="country">База стран</li>');
    post.country = 0;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'currenci') {
    $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="currenci">База валют</li>');
    post.currenci = 0;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'package') {
    $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="package">База пакетов</li>');
    post.package = 0;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'activitidirection') {
    $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="activitidirection">Направление деят-ти</li>');
    post.activitidirection = 0;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'branch') {
    $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="branch">Отрасль</li>');
    post.branch = 0;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'industrialdirection') {
    $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="industrialdirection">Промышленное направление</li>');
    post.industrialdirection = 0;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'measuri') {
    $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="measuri">Ед. Измерения</li>');
    post.measuri = 0;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'fo') {
    $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="fo">Федеральный округ</li>');
    post.fo = 0;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'region') {
    $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="region">Регион</li>');
    post.region = 0;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'logistic') {
    $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="logistic">Логистика</li>');
    post.logistic = 0;
  }
  if ($(this).data('metod') == 'quality') {
    $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="quality">Качество</li>');
    post.quality = 0;
  }
  // row.find('.tab_add').text(post.r_name);
  console.log(post);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <p class="cursor_pointer" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
    Информационные базы
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </p>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu infobase_drop">
    <li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="country">База стран</li>
    <li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="currenci">База валют</li>
    <li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="package">База пакетов</li>
    <li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="activitidirection">Направление деят-ти</li>
    <li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="branch">Отрасль</li>
    <li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="industrialdirection">Промышленное направление</li>
    <li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="measuri">Ед. Измерения</li>
    <li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="fo">Федеральный округ</li>
    <li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="region">Регион</li>
    <li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="logistic">Логистика</li>
    <li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="quality">Качество</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Локальное хранилище в помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем код  [имеется в виду html?] отправлять на сервер? Создай модель данных и работой с ней.

К примеру: `[{title: "SomeObj_1", isExist: true}, {title: "SomeObj_2", isExist: false}, {title: "SomeObj_3", isExist: true}]` — и в зависимости от параметра **"isExist"** строишь элемент либо в выпадающем списке, либо в области просмотра.

Соответственно, сериализуешь и отправляешь на сервак JSON, сохраняешь его в БД.

@@@

***profit***